# Windows API to set lock screen picture

Tags: winapi

Windows allows users to set the lock screen background to Slideshow but makes the user pick the albums for the slide show.

I have a device on the shop floor that I need to set the pictures programatically and cannot rely on the shop floor staff to know what folders to look in.

Is there an API where I can set the lock screen background?

Comment: [LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.lockscreen.setimagefileasync) looks promising. [Sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Personalization/cpp/SetLockScreenImage.xaml.cpp).